# http status 404 – not found in jsp, servlet on Tomcat server

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, http-status-code-404

i am newbie in java. this is my first application developing with jsp and servlet.

when i click submit button, the result is show that `http status 404`.

Error is

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> **Type** Status Report
>
> **Message** /DemoApp/add
>
> **Description** The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

In **web.xml**,

```java
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.saunghninoo.AddServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/add</url-pattern>
  </servlet>
```

Index.html

```html
<form action="add" method="post">
                Enter 1st no: <input type="text" name="num1" class="form-control"><br>
                Enter 2nd no: <input type="text" name="num2" class="form-control"><br>
                
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
              </form>
```

IN **AddServlet.java**,

```java
package com.saunghninoo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class AddServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num1"));
        int j = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num2"));
        
        int k= i+j;
        
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        
        out.println("result is "+ k);
    }
}
```

Please, Help me!!

Answer (score 1):

In **web.xml**, Change like this

```java
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.saunghninoo.AddServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>abc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/add</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```